# How to install the GTK+2 or GTK+3 tookliks for Python 3 development on Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, gtk, python3

I want to make a GTK+2 or GTK+3 application in Python 3.

For GTK+2, I tried installing `PyGTK`, but I cannot find any version of `PyGTK` for Python 3 within Debian's repositories.

For GTK+2, I followed the tutorials in the [Python Gtk+3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html). I installed `python3-gi`, but when I type `python3` in the terminal, then type `from gi.repository import Gtk`, it reports this:

> ImportError: cannot import name Gtk

How can I install GTK+2 or GTK+3 for use with Python 3 on Debian?

Comment: What do you consider "**the** Python 3 IDE"?

Comment: Oh, maybe the word is not "IDE", but "IDLE" or some similar name, run by typing `python3` in a terminal window.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this under Linux Mint 17.1 (i.e. Gtk can be imported). Did you start `idle3` and not `idle`? (I asked about the IDE as there are multiple and I only had WingIDE installed, not idle3).

Comment: I just opened a terminal, typed `python3`, confirmed it is version 3, then typed out `from gi.repository import Gtk`, and pressed enter. I also tried saving some of the example files from that tutorial I linked, but they reported the same error that Gtk was not found. I search Debian's repositories, but cannot determine which package might contain the Gtk needed by Python.

Comment: Is `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` in your `sys.path`? ( `python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` ) The gi directory should be there ( `ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi`)

Comment: Yes, it lists that.

Comment: And just doing `import gi` from the commandline.

Comment: I typed `python3`, then `import gi` and this prints no errors.

Comment: My only guess is that some of the dependencies are not installed.